# ASP.Net Global / Page Scope Variables

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm in the process of converting a classic ASP application to ASP.Net and have hit a brick wall to do with global variables (or page scope variables).  As a note, the application is not a typical one in that it doesn't build HTML.  Instead it gets AJAX requests and returns JSON strings, so as such doesn't use a lot of asp.net functionality.  First time for a long time that googling hasn't lead me to an answer!

In the asp code we use a number of global variables defined in variables.asp, eg:

```
<%
dim lId
%>
```

This asp is then included in all pages.  There are a number of other include files that reference these variables, along with the pages themselves.

For asp.net the closest I can find is to have variables.aspx:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript" RunAt="Server">
shared dim lId as integer
</SCRIPT>
```

However, I realise that this variable is much more 'global' than how it worked in .asp, and that it can cause threading issues etc, and that they effecitvely work like using the Application() object, which is not what I'm after.

Effectively what I need is to be able to declare a variable that can be referenced in other includes, and in the base page, whose scope/lifetime is only for the processing of that page.

At this stage, the only thing I can think of is to use Session variables, and to clear them at the end of each processing, but am dreading the work / issues of such a conversion

Comment: is this an asp.net webforms app or asp.net mvc app?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class in your asp.net project to store these static variables. If they are configuration parameters, they should go in the web.config file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  They are not configuration parameters, and they are not static.  They are used to keep track of the id of the record that you are modifying, whether you are adding / modifying / deleting a record etc, all things that vary on each post.  With creating a class, I experimented briefly, but it became chicken and the egg - I needed a global variable to hold the instance of the class?

Comment: Doesn't sound like they are global variables. Maybe you should be using viewstate to store them.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I might end up doing something like the following:

```
shared dim gv as New GlobalVariables

public class GlobalVariables
    public property Id as integer
        Get
            Id = cint(HttpContext.Current.Items("id"))
        End Get
        set (ByVal aiValue as integer)
            HttpContext.Current.Items("id") = aiValue
        End Set
    end property
end class
```

Then where ever I currently reference "lId", I need to replace with "gv.Id".

gv will still be global, but given it is looking in current.items I shouldn't have any thread issues.